# What exactly is a basis matrix in LPP?

Tags: linear-programming

I'm studying simplex for solving a LPP. $A$ is a $m\times n$ matix. $$Ax=b$$Then the book says:

> Let $x$ be a basic feasible solution to the standard form problem. 
>   Let $$B(1), B(2),\cdots B(m)$$ be the indices of the basic variables and   let $$B=[A_{B(1)}\cdots A_{B(m)}]$$ be the corresponding basis matrix.

I can't understand what's this $B$ a basis for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the columns of $B$ are independent and the columns of $B$ indeed span $\mathbb{R}^m$.

We can always solve $$Bx_B=b$$ for any given $b$.

Comment: Ya, true. But since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, why do we care about $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: the BFS of the standard form of LP has this property that $n-m$ entries are $0$ for sure, those are the non-basic variables. Those potentially non-zero positions are obtained by solving the linear system above.

Comment: Okay. I got it, thanks!